# Sharepoint Limited-access user permission lockdown mode is enabled, open word file in desktop app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have enabled "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode", and my recipient open the word file by desktop app ,notice that the file is open as "READ ONLY" and cannot save the changes . Anyone know how to solve this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Library settings -> Versioning Settings -> Check whether set "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" as "Yes".

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Already did ,this Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" option is set as  'No' .

Comment: Whether this file has been checked out by others before?